# Some problem about inline function in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, inline, msvc14

I'm doing some (maybe exotic) experiments about C++ inline functions in VS2019:

source1:

```
#include "pch.h"

inline int inline_func(int i) {
    return  i;
}

void testinline1()
{
    inline_func(0);
}
```

source2:

```
#include "pch.h"

inline int inline_func(int i) {
    return  i*i ;
}

void testinline2()
{
    inline_func(0);
}
```

main source:

```
#include "pch.h"

inline int inline_func(int i);
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{   
    int i = inline_func(2);
}
```

According to "Storage classes of inline functions" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function,

> In C++, a function defined inline will, if required, emit a function
>   shared among translation units, typically by putting it into the
>   common section of the object file for which it is needed. The function
>   must have the same definition everywhere, always with the inline
>   qualifier.

The definitions of inline_func in source1 and source2 is different so there should be errors, but there is no such error in VS2019.

The result of i in main() is 2 which is from the inline_func in source1, this seems to be a random choice by the building process since if I comment testinline1 in source1, then i will become 4 since the inline_func in source1 won't show up in the object file without being used in the same source. When I comment testinline2 in source2 too there will be undefined symbol error for inline_func as expected.

Why does these happen? Is this where C++ doesn't cover or only MSVC doesn't cover?

**Updated after answered**:

Here is a better example:

source1:

```
#include "pch.h"

int non_inline_func();
inline int inline_func2() {
    return  non_inline_func();
}

static int non_inline_func()
{
    return 1;
}

int public_func1() 
{
    return inline_func2();
}
```

source2:

```
#include "pch.h"

int non_inline_func();
inline int inline_func2() {
    return  non_inline_func();
}

static int non_inline_func()
{
    return 2;
}

int public_func2()
{
    return inline_func2();
}
```

main source:

```
#include "pch.h"

int public_func1();
int public_func2();

void TestInline()
{
    int i =public_func1();
    int j= public_func2();
}
```

The result is i=j=1. The definition of the inline functions are the same here. This should violate this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule

> name lookup from within each definition finds the same entities (after
>   overload-resolution)

Comment: _The definitions of inline_func in source1 and source2 is different so there should be errors_ This will cause Undefined Behavior. It's a violation of ODR if I'm right. Another question is whether diagnostic is required by the standard...

Comment: Found on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline): _There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical._ and _If an inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the behavior is undefined._ Diagnostics not mentioned (or I overlooked it).

Comment: The end of the first sentence, "typically [...]", is a figment of the author's imagination.

Comment: "there should be errors" Sure, you've made one.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have not seen counterexamples so far, have you?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671956/same-class-name-in-different-c-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this One Definition Rule (ODR) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule):

> If all these requirements are satisfied, the program behaves as if there is only one definition in the entire program. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

If you have an ODR-violation (which you have since the two definitions are not identical) the compiler doesn't have to emit a warning or error message.

Comment: Does this mean that it's bad to use #if and macros in an inline function in a header file unless the preprocessing result is sure to be the same in any potential sources that use that header?

Comment: @jw_ Yes that could be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, in MSVS2019 ISO C++ 14...

The inline function :

```
inline uint32_t hanoi(int a) { __asm  bsf eax, a } // Solve arbitrary 'Tower of Hanoi' round
```

Called with either :

```
int numMoves = (1<<numDisks)-1; /* Calculate number of moves needed to solve */

// Print full Tower Of Hanoi solution
for (int i = 1;i < numMoves;i++) {
    printf("move disk %u %s\n", hanoi(i), hanoi(i) & 1 ? "left" : "right");
}
```

or, just :

```
hanoi(1);
```

Doesn't inline.  It always results in a *"Call"* being emitted by the compiler : /

Same when I :

- use std::cout ... like a good boy ; )
- call the function directly *(discarding)* or;
- call the function directly *(utilizing return value)*

and irrespective of whether :

- Passed parameter is immediate/literal
- Passed parameter is stack local variable
- Passed parameter is heap allocated static global
- Function is changed to be `uint32_t f(void) { return 1; }` <-- surprised me!

I notice that folks far cleverer than I have complained about similar in-lining issues in VS2015 and VS2017 - each comparing it to identical code in CLANG and GCC, whos compilers don't seem to have any issue : /  Each time MS appear to have identified it as a compiler issue.

TBH, it looks like VS may just be a little 'fragile' when it comes to in-lining functions :(

Just my 2c

**\o/** - *"don't shoot!"*