# why linker cannt find my class even though i have set all thing correct

Tags: c++, g++

i created a class Log with some methods and variables and i added it to header file but no matter what i do linker can find my class

the error i got:

```
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `Log::setLevel(int)'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Log::info(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ep.h"

class Log;

int main()
{
    start();

    Log log;

    log.setLevel(log.logLevlInfo);
    log.info("infoooooooooo");

    end();
}
```

this is my ep.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class Log
{
private:
    int m_logLevel;

public:
    int logLevlInfo = 2;
    int logLevlWarn = 1;
    int logLevlError = 0;

public:
    void setLevel(int level)
    {
        m_logLevel = level;
    }

    void warn(const char* message)
    {
        if(m_logLevel <= 1)
        {
        std::cout << "warning -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void error(const char* message)
    {
        if(m_logLevel <= 0)
        {
        std::cout << "error -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void info(const char* message)
    {
        if(m_logLevel <= 2)
        {
        std::cout << "info -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

void log(const char* st)
{
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
}

void end()
{
    std::cout << "press any button to exit";
    std::cin.get();
}

void start()
{
    system("cls");
}
```

and finaly my ep.h

```
void end();
void start();

class Log
{
private:
    int m_logLevel;

public:
    int logLevlInfo;
    int logLevlWarn;
    int logLevlError;

public:
    void setLevel(int level);
    void warn(const char* message);
    void error(const char* message);
    void info(const char* message);
};
```

this is how i compile this

```
g++ *.cpp
```

im begginer, i dont know wy this happening...

i tried both `g++ *.cpp` and `g++ -c *.cpp` + `g++ *.o`
nothing worked

### edit 1:
i tried moving class to header and it worked(answer of Wakeel Furqan Ahmed) but what is the problem of not moving class to header

new code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ep.h"
//No need to declare class Log here.
int main() {

    Log log;

    log.setLevel(log.logLevlError);
    log.info("infoooooooooo");

}
```

ep.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class Log
{
private:
    int m_logLevel;
public:
    int logLevlInfo = 2;
    int logLevlWarn = 1;
    int logLevlError = 0;

    void setLevel(int level) {
        m_logLevel = level;
    }

    void warn(const char* message) {
        if (m_logLevel <= 1) {
            std::cout << "warning -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void error(const char* message) {
        if (m_logLevel <= 0) {
            std::cout << "error -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void info(const char* message) {
        if (m_logLevel <= 2) {
            std::cout << "info -> " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

ep.h

```
class Log {
private:
    int m_logLevel;

public:
    int logLevlInfo;
    int logLevlWarn;
    int logLevlError;

    void setLevel(int level);
    void warn(const char* message);
    void error(const char* message);
    void info(const char* message);
};
```

error:

```
PS C:\Users\Sarba\Desktop\Projects\Programming\cpp-project> g++ *.cpp
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Sarba\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfgOd21.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `Log::setLevel(int)'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Sarba\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfgOd21.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `Log::info(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: check if u have g++ installed, by writting g++ --version in terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: put class declaration in header instead of in cpp file

Comment: See [Same class name in different C++ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671956/same-class-name-in-different-c-files) and [How to separate a class and its member functions into header and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/how-to-separate-a-class-and-its-member-functions-into-header-and-source-files)

Comment: @m_mdi See/read the duplicates in the dupe list. They are there for a reason. Also [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
The issue you're encountering is related to the linker not being able to find the definitions for the Log class functions that are used in your main.cpp file. This happens because you've declared the Log class in both main.cpp and ep.cpp, but the definitions of the Log class functions are missing. To fix this, you should define the Log class and its member functions in a separate .cpp file, and then compile all the .cpp files together

**Solution:**
the main.cpp becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ep.h"
//No need to declare class Log here.
int main() {
    start();

    Log log;

    log.setLevel(Log::logLevlInfo);
    log.info("infoooooooooo");

    end();
}
```

other than this, it is recommended to seperate the class funtions declarations and definitions
so u get ep.h & ep.cpp(which u already have, but incorrectly)

ep.h:

```
void end();
void start();

class Log {
private:
    int m_logLevel;

public:
    static int logLevlInfo;
    static int logLevlWarn;
    static int logLevlError;

    void setLevel(int level);
    void warn(const char* message);
    void error(const char* message);
    void info(const char* message);
};
```

ep.cpp

```
#include "ep.h"

int Log::logLevlInfo = 2;
int Log::logLevlWarn = 1;
int Log::logLevlError = 0;

void Log::setLevel(int level) {
    m_logLevel = level;
}

void Log::warn(const char* message) {
    if (m_logLevel <= 1) {
        std::cout << "warning -> " << message << std::endl;
    }
}

void Log::error(const char* message) {
    if (m_logLevel <= 0) {
        std::cout << "error -> " << message << std::endl;
    }
}

void Log::info(const char* message) {
    if (m_logLevel <= 2) {
        std::cout << "info -> " << message << std::endl;
    }
}
```

compile:

```
g++ main.cpp ep.cpp -o <ur_program_name>
```

Edit: Since u didn't understand the issue. U just need to define or declare any thing just one. the compiler is smart enough to undertand the code, u dont need to tell the compiler that there exists a class called 'Log' every single time (like u did in main (class Log;) and in ep.cpp)
the .h call header file is for that. (can relate to word heading)

now see u declared ur class in
ep.h

```
class Log{
  # all the code of data member & flns
};
```

now in ep.cpp (u just simply give the definition of those flns in .h)

well here rises another question, how is the compiler 'smart enough' to know things.

well, it's called Resolution operator (::) (it resolves / tell compiler what belongs to what)

so

```
void Log::setLevel(int level) {
    m_logLevel = level;
}
```

this says that "setlevel belongs to class Log"

I hope, now its more clear

Comment: this somehow worked, but can you explain what happend to the `class` inside `ep.cpp` there is no `class Log{}`, is the problem really about how i wrote class in ep.cpp i mean what you mentioned that i declare class in main.cpp was not realy the problem because i had that linking problem before that.

Comment: i added an edit, can you please look at it an explain what is the my code??

Comment: @m_mdi See/read the duplicates in the dupe list. They are there for a reason. Also [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Comment: oh i see u are new to programming, i have explained more. Plz mark as answer if it resolves ur issue